# return statement not working with try catch in DAO java spring

Tags: java, spring, try-catch, return

I have this function in userDAO

```
public List<Country> findAllCountries() {

         try {

                 Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
                 Query query = session.createQuery("FROM  Country");
                 return  query.list();

         } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println(e);
                }


        }
```

The problem is that eclipse is giving error that telling me to either use void in return or add return statement , if i remove try catch then it works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return something (or throw an Exception) from your catch block as well:

```
catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
         return null;
}

catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
         throw new RuntimeException("DAO failed", e);
}
```

Otherwise there will be a code path through the method without a return statement.

Answer (score 2):

I'd write it this way.  I don't know what you should be doing to close your Session or clean up in a finally block.  This will make Eclipse happy:

```
public List<Country> findAllCountries() 
{    
    List<Country> countries = new ArrayList<Country>();

    try 
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        Query query = session.createQuery("FROM  Country");
        countries = query.list();    
    } 
    catch (Exception e) 
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return countries;
}
```